# CSS - link hover doesn't work

Tags: hyperlink, hover, anchor, mailto

Does anyone know how to make CSS link hover properties work for links that don't link to another html page or anchor?

For example this works:

```
<a href="page1.html">Page1</a>
<a href="#page9">Link</a>

a:hover,a:visited:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:link,a:visited{
color:#555;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

But the moment I change the link to something that's not an anchor or an html file, let's say a mailto:

```
<a href='mailto:bla@bla.com'>Send email</a>
```

It no longer changes color when I hover over the link.
Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overriding your own styles. Try

```
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link, a:visited
        {
            color: #555;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover, a:visited:hover
        {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a:link, just a will do fine when defining your anchor tag style, however, if for some reason you do need it then you need to define your hover style more specifically than your link style.

```
a:link:hover,a:visited:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:link,a:visited{
color:#555;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

or

```
a:hover,a:visited:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
a,a:visited{
color:#555;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

will fix your problem